# Parsing date with DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

- I am struggling in converting string to a date.
- I iterated through different methods mentioned on StackOverflow starting from strtotime() but never managed to correctly parse it.
- Below is my minimal (non-)working example of my latest effort this time using DateTime::createFromFormat.

  ```
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s e', '16 Jul 2015 05:00:00 UT');
  ```

  `var_dump($date);` returns `bool(false)`

Could someone suggest what am I doing wrong bore I pulled remaining hair from my head? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UT isn't a valid timezone identifier.  Did you mean UTC?

This works:

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s e', '16 Jul 2015 05:00:00 UTC');`

Comment: Thank you so much David R. and Dse for your comments. It turned out that the rss I am trying to parse includes a non-compliant time zone UT (as opposed to UTC). `str_replace(" UT"," UTC",$date);` solved the problem. Once again thank you David R. for spotting this, I kept missing it! –

Comment: No prob, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider your language version that is if php means 5.4 not support the date function you mentioned

Comment: According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), DateTime::createFromFormat works from PHP >= 5.3.

Comment: No that is not true I have faced the same problem because of php version that time my php version also 5.4 but not working after updating my php version it is working